Changing Selection Mode in Auto Desk Forge Viewer through Settings
When we change the Selection Mode from "First Object" to "Leaf Object," the model loads quickly. However, when we switch back to "First Object" and check, the model loads slowly and the screen gets hung. This slowness occurs only when we change to "First Object" in Selection Mode.
Please suggest some solutions.
We tried by web-referenced coding to resolve the hanging issue and slowness but unable to get a solution
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

  // Get the viewer div

  const viewerDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');

  // Initialize the viewer object


  enter code here

  const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);

  viewer.start();

  // Ensure event listeners are added only once

  viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT, onToolbarCreated);

  viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, Loadedevent);

  // Initialize the AggregatedView

  const view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();

  view.init(viewerDiv, options3d);

  // Use the same viewer instance

  const aggregatedViewer = view.viewer;

  // Set custom profile settings


  const customProfileSettings = {

    settings: {

      reverseMouseZoomDir: true,

      reverseHorizontalLookDirection: true,

      selectionMode: 1 // enum value, 0 is default 'First Object' is 1

    }

  };

  const customProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customProfileSettings);

  viewer.setProfile(customProfile);
  viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, switchSelectionMode(1));

  // Optimize viewer settings

  viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false); // Disable ambient occlusion and antialiasing

  viewer.setGroundShadow(false); // Disable ground shadow

  viewer.setGroundReflection(false); // Disable ground reflection

  viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true); // Enable progressive rendering

  // Load all manifests

  const tasks = models.map(md => loadManifest(md.urn, aggregatedViewer));

  Promise.all(tasks)

    .then(docs => Promise.resolve(docs.map(doc => {

      const bubbles = doc.getRoot().search({
        type: 'geometry',
        role: '3d'
      });

      const bubble = bubbles[0];

      if (!bubble) return null;

      return bubble;

    })))

    .then(bubbles => view.setNodes(bubbles));

});

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
function loadManifest(documentId, viewer) {

  debugger;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (doc) => {

      doc.downloadAecModelData(() => resolve(doc));

      // New code for handling selection changes

      viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (event) => {

        if (!event.selections || event.selections.length <= 0 || event.selections.length > 1) return;

        const selSet = event.selections[0];

        const dbIds = selSet.dbIdArray;

        const model = selSet.model;

        const dbId = dbIds[0];


        model.getProperties(dbId, function(data) {

          if (FromPage == '') {

            if (FromSelection == '') {

              if (Count === 0) {

                let instanceTree = model.getInstanceTree();

                let parentId = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(dbId);

                var objectid = parentId + 1;

                if (objectid === PreviousParentId) {

                  Count = 1;

                  selectionchangecount = 0;

                } else {

                  viewer.select(parentId, model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);

                  Count = 1;

                  selectionchangecount = 0;

                }

                PreviousParentId = parentId;

              } else {

                itemobject = dbId;

                selectionchangecount = selectionchangecount + 1;

                if (selectionchangecount == fileselectioncount) {

                  Count = 0;

                  selectionchangecount = 0;

                }

              }

            } else {

              selectionchangecount = selectionchangecount + 1;

              if (selectionchangecount == filecount) {

                FromSelection = '';

                selectionchangecount = 0;

              }

              itemobject = dbId;

            }

          } else {

            FromPage = '';

            itemobject = dbId;

          }

        });

      });

    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, reject);

  });

}

}
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

// Example function to switch selection mode efficiently
function switchSelectionMode(newMode) {
  // Check if the mode has actually changed
  if (newMode !== viewer.getSelectionMode()) {
    // Disable unnecessary updates during mode change
    viewer.impl.disableRequests(true);

    // Change selection mode
    viewer.setSelectionMode(newMode);

    // Re-enable updates after mode change
    viewer.impl.disableRequests(false);
  }
}


There is a blog post on how you can find what settings a UI component is manipulating:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/change-viewer-settings
E.g. in this case it's preferences.set("selectionMode")

You can set Selection Mode to Leaf Object using NOP_VIEWER.prefs.set("selectionMode", 0)

we have shared code for your refrence , we need solution to avoid slowness and hanging issue while accessing selection mode especially for first object.

Can you reproduce the issue with any model?
Can you check what exactly in your code is making the model load slower when "Selection Mode" is set to "First Object"? - i.e. remove things from your code until the issue goes away.
I checked with this online sample and see no difference in the loading time of the Revit model depending on the "Selection Mode"
https://codepen.io/autodesk-platform-services/pen/MWqmXxG
viewer.prefs.set("selectionMode", 1)


